# Simple web-based version control

Tags: version-control

I need a simple, web-based version control tool.  'Version Control' probably implies a lot of functionality I don't need such as diff and merge.

Basically, I have a lot of non-programmer types working on binary files (think Photoshop PSDs), and I would just like a way to check them out and in, and keep previous versions.

Web-based would be ideal, I just want something better than nested folders on a shared drive.

Suggestions?

Comment: Are you looking for a script for installing locally or an online service?

Comment: I think this question belongs on Super User.

Comment: Look into `mod_dav` or utilize one of the VCS commandline tools to stash away uploaded things.

Comment: Looking for something like a PHP script that I can install on a web hosting account.  I'm not opposed to an online service, but it needs to be free.

Comment: Ended up with [IntraVersion](http://top-cat.com/intraversion.php).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try [asvcs](http://sourceforge.net/projects/asvcs/): it's web-based and very simple. My advice would be to try one of the known solutions (svn, git, mercurial, even bazaar) and use only the features you need.

Comment: ASVCS is close to what I'm looking for.  Does it support binary files?  I also couldn't tell from the documentation if it stored all of the files in a database, or in the filesystem?

Comment: Files are stored in a database. I don't know about binary files. More info http://asvcs.com/node/15

Comment: Went with [IntraVersion](http://top-cat.com/intraversion.php), a branch of ASVCS.

Answer (score 2):

[Dropbox](http://www.dropbox.com/) provides a web interface and can be used as a simple version control system.

Comment: That may be a good fallback plan if I can't find anything else.

Answer (score 1):

Try building something around git. (Or maybe set up a private github account.)

Comment: I've done this twice now. It's very powerful, but it take a lot of upfront time to get it right.

Answer (score 1):

[Springloops](http://www.springloops.com/v2/) has what you're looking for. However, it's a paid service. Integrates nicely with [Basecamp](http://basecamphq.com/)

You could also use [Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/home). [There's version control of sorts](https://www.dropbox.com/features). But history is kept only for 1 month.

And there's [github](https://github.com/)

Answer (score 0):

I know through experience that Atlassian's [Confluence](http://www.atlassian.com/software/confluence/) wiki solution will do versioning for binary uploads. I'm sure there are probably other open source alternatives available as well.